# How to parse src from img tag in VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel, html-parsing

I have a question relating to HTML parsing. I have a website with some products and I would like to catch the URL from images into my current spreadsheet.
This spreadsheet is quite big but contains ItemNbr in 3rd column, I expect the URL in the 27th column and one row corresponds to one product (item).

My idea is to fetch the URL of 'regular' OR 'large' OR 'verylarge' images (It doesn't really matter). Here is the structure of the website (among various other div):

```
<div id="MainDisplay" class="miMaindisplay">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/verylarge/12425/nl" id="ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_jqzoom" class="loupe">
        <div class="zoomPad">
            <img src="http://www.example.com/regular/12425/nl" id="ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_PreviewImage" class="miPreviewImage">
            <div class="zoomPup"></div>
            <div class="zoomWindow">
                <div class="zoomWrapper">
                    <div class="zoomWrapperTitle"></div>
                    <div class="zoomWrapperImage">
                        <img src="http://www.example.com/large/12425/nl">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="zoomPreload">Loading zoom</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I could get the URL in the JS console with this line:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_PreviewImage').src;
```

And the answer is:

```
http://www.example.com/regular/12425/nl
```

But without success in VBA. Here is my code snippet:

```
Sub ParseImage()

    Dim Cell As Integer
    Dim ItemNbr As String

    Dim AElement As Object
    Dim AElements As IHTMLElementCollection

    Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody

    Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLBody = HTMLDoc.body

    For Cell = 1 To 5                            'I iterate through the file row by row

        ItemNbr = Cells(Cell, 3).Value           'ItemNbr are in the 3rd Column of my spreadsheet

        IE.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com/?item=" & ItemNbr, False
        IE.send

        While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

        Set AElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each AElement In AElements
            If AElement.id = "ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_PreviewImage" Then
                Cells(Cell, 27) = AElement.src     'I write URL in the 27th column
            End If
        Next AElement

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))

Next Cell
```

End Sub

I obviously included some references as follows:

[image: References]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements you are targetting are identified by an id in your HTML page, the more straightforward way to get to it is to use the getElementById method of the HTML document object.

Try and replace this section

```
Set AElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each AElement In AElements
    If AElement.id = "ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_PreviewImage" Then
        Cells(Cell, 27) = AElement.src     'I write URL in the 27th column
    End If
Next AElement
```

with something like

```
set previewImg = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_PageContent_MultiImage_PreviewImage")
If not previewImg is Nothing then Cells(Cell, 27) = previewImg.getAttribute("src")
```